# Maven Project is not building

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to create a Maven project to incorporate Gson into, however, whenever I try to run it, I get 13 errors all saying: "The project was not built due to "release 7 is not found in the system"." It all says its at line 1, column 1, however, I don't think there are any problems with it. It is

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

I went with the default VSCode option to create a Maven project and have only changed the pom.xml file

Comment: Please include the **exact** error (formatted) and a minimal pom that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository, may also be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not explain enough about your error condition. I suggest you first try an utterly simple project to get all your tools in place and functioning. Here is one such simple project.

### *Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*

For VS Code as your IDE, consider using the new [*Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/) from Oracle Corp, free of cost.

### Add dependency to your Maven POM

Grab the dependency coordinates from a Maven repository, like [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is an example of my modified version of the Maven *QuickStart* archetype, with an added dependency for GSON.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExGson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ExGson</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0-M9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, change the imports in the test file to use modern Unit Jupiter.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
```

Example app:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Example of using GSON via Maven POM.
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Hello World!" );

        Gson gson = new Gson ( );
        String json = gson.toJson ( new Person ( "Wendy Melvoin" ) );
        System.out.println ( "json = " + json );
    }
}

record Person( String name ){}
```

When run:

```
Hello World!
json = {"name":"Wendy Melvoin"}
```

Comment: It still throws the exact same error: "The project was not built due to "release 7 is not found in the system". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent"

Comment: @Coder6421 Did you start a fresh new project, and immediately compile and run successfully? Did you then go on to use exactly my POM? Did you install a JDK for Java 21? Did you configure the project within your IDE to use that JDK? You should learn to think through your problem, and give full details.